# click on the wrong location when use /dev/uinput on Android

Tags: android

The function of my project looks like [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing). But a little different from that.
I have a server program running on Android and a client running on PC. I want to control mobile phone by operating on PC.

Most part of this project has finished, but a little error happeded in the step of controling. May be you know that we always 
using [the user level input subsystem](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) to achive the goal for responsing to operating command coming 
from PC client. I made reference to other people when write this part of program. In additional, I am new to Android, so something is out of my control.

ok, I will tell the details as below.
For example, when you click mouse or press some keys on PC, the server receive this command through some protocol such as 
[RFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFB_protocol), and get relative information about your command event e.g. button mask(can decide left or 
right mouse clicked) or position(X, Y coordinate). Following the three steps to send command to Android.

First, creating an input device by open devices of "/dev/uinput" in android.
Second, inject relative events to input subsystem.
Then, write events to virtual input subsystem.

Simplified code:

```
//First ADN SECOND STEPS:
    int initial()
    {
        int inputfd = -1;

        uinput_fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

        /* Set device to handle following types of events: */

      /* Key and button repetition events */
        if (ioctl(uinput_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_REP) == -1)
            return -1;

        /* Absolute pointer motions */
        if (ioctl(uinput_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_ABS) == -1)
            return -1;
        /* Configure device to handle absolute x and y axis. */
        if (ioctl(uinput_fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_X) == -1)
            goto err;
        if (ioctl(uinput_fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_Y) == -1)
            return -1;

        /* Synchronization events, this is probably set implicitely too. */
        if (ioctl(uinput_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_SYN) == -1)
            return -1;


        struct uinput_user_dev user_dev;
        /* Set device-specific information. */
        memset(&user_dev, 0, sizeof(user_dev));
        strncpy(user_dev.name, device_name, UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE);
        user_dev.id.bustype = BUS_USB;
        user_dev.id.vendor = 1;
        user_dev.id.product = 1;
        user_dev.id.version = 1;

        //minor tweak to support ABSolute events
        user_dev.absmin[ABS_X] = 0;
        user_dev.absmax[ABS_X] = 799;
        user_dev.absfuzz[ABS_X] = 0;
        user_dev.absflat[ABS_X] = 0;

        user_dev.absmin[ABS_Y] = 0;
        user_dev.absmax[ABS_Y] = 479;
        user_dev.absfuzz[ABS_Y] = 0;
        user_dev.absflat[ABS_Y] = 0;

        if (write(uinput_fd, &user_dev, sizeof(user_dev)) != sizeof(user_dev))
            return -1;

        if (ioctl(uinput_fd, UI_DEV_CREATE) == -1)
            return -1;
    }

//THREE STEP:
    //call by ptrEvent
    int suinput_write(int uinput_fd, uint16_t type, uint16_t code, int32_t value)
    {
        struct input_event event, nullevent;
        memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
        gettimeofday(&event.time, 0); /* This should not be able to fail ever.. */
        event.type = type;
        event.code = code;
        event.value = value;
        if (write(uinput_fd, &event, sizeof(event)) != sizeof(event))
            return -1;

        return 0;
    }
    //begin to deal with event
    void ptrEvent(int buttonMask, int x, int y, rfbClientPtr cl)
    {

        static int leftClicked=0;

        if ( inputfd == -1 )
            return;

        if (buttonMask & 1)
        { //left btn clicked
            leftClicked=1;

            suinput_write(inputfd, EV_ABS, ABS_X, x);
            suinput_write(inputfd, EV_ABS, ABS_Y, y);
            suinput_write(inputfd,EV_KEY,BTN_TOUCH,1);
            suinput_write(inputfd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
        }
        else if (leftClicked)
        { //left btn released
            leftClicked=0;
            suinput_write(inputfd, EV_ABS, ABS_X, x);
            suinput_write(inputfd, EV_ABS, ABS_Y, y);
            suinput_write(inputfd,EV_KEY,BTN_TOUCH,0);
            suinput_write(inputfd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
        }
    }
```

Android devices has resolution of 800*480. and client picture also has the same size. I debug the above code and find that
server receive the right location from event message. In function of ptrEvent, X and Y is right corresponding to the real
click position occured in PC. But from the actual pressed position showed on Android, there is a different from that. As you see,
I set the max absolute range of Android virtual input devices to same as actual resolution, so obviously there is no bias between client and server
coordinate. why that happened?

Comment: `corresponding to the real click position occured in PC.`. What do you consider the real click position. Is it according to one corner of the picture? And in the same units as its resolution? So it the picture was  800*480 and the position is 400,240 you indicate the middle?

Comment: @greenapps yeah, I print out the x and y in function of 'ptrEvent'. I am not sure it's a very percise coordinate, but from the approximate position it's right. For example, i click on the picture three times followed by the upper left, upper right and lower right corner, so print out of (10,20), (760, 20), (760,754). From that we can see this coordinate is make the upper left corner for reference and may be correct relative to actual resolution of 800*400. so if i click in the middle, it will get (400,240).
what do you mean the same units as its resolution?

Comment: `same units as its resolution`. Well if a picture of resolution 800*480 has beeen scaled to display as 600*360. If you then say 'i clicked at position 400,280 then what did you mean?

Comment: But i still do not understand your problem. You posted a lot of code transfering some values. But is transfering the problem? Isn't it more in  calculating some offsets and corresponding coordinates?